# Proper architecture for a Client/Server communication

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture, client-server, messaging

I'm thinking about the best way to implement a client/server communication.
The idea is quite simple: a client sends some message to the sever/or calls some method on a server side and receives back some response (a message).

I see the following options:

1. WCF duplex service
2. Client/Server use 2 msmq: 1st that keeps
   the messages from all the clients and server reads them. the 2nd is
   the server's responses and the clients read them. I don't like this
   approach.
3. TCP/IP communication as a chat messenger. Also don't
   like much this idea because it's too messy, obsolete, etc.

Maybe there is a better way or some interesting/new technology/framework?
Please advise.

Comment: What is your client?

Comment: Does this need to work over the Internet or just a LAN?  Using domains?  Can your app work disconnected (messaging) or do you require always-connected (RPC)?

Comment: It's a good question: what is my client. And the answer is: I don't know. The major focus is on a server side, so I presume the client could be any: a desktop app or a web browser. Maybe it makes sense to integrate SignalR?

Answer (score 0):

How about using [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)?

If your client is a web application or a mobile application, this framework is ideal for such client-server communication.

It has a lot built in, and utilises HTTP as it was originally intended, a data communication protocol.

[Here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/07/Where-does-ASPNET-Web-API-Fit) is an *old* but still **very useful** post about some common uses cases, advantages and disadvantages for ASP.NET Web API.